# On arithmetic functions whose Dirichlet series has a special kind of abscissa of absolute convergence

Tags: analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, dirichlet-series, multiplicative-function, dirichlet-convolution

For a function $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb C$ , let $\sigma_c(f) , \sigma_a(f)$ denote the abscissa of convergence and the abscissa of absolute convergence respectively of the Dirichlet series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {f(n)}{n^s}$ .

Can we characterize all arithmetic functions $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb C$ with $f(1)\ne 0$ , such that $\sigma_a(f) \ge \sigma_c(f^{-1})$ , where $f^{-1}$ denotes the "inverse" of $f$ with respect to Dirichlet convolution ( the inverse exists as we have assumed $f(1)\ne 0$ ) ?  If this is difficult , then how about a characterization of arithmetic functions $f$ satisfying $\sigma_a(f) \ge \sigma_a(f^{-1})$ ? If these cannot be done very well, then can we at least characterize such functions among the multiplicative functions ?

Definitely, any completely multiplicative arithmetic function satisfies the condition, as for such a function $f$ , $f^{-1}(n)=\mu(n)f(n)$ ; and since $|\mu(n)f(n)| \le |f(n)|$ , we get $\sigma_a(f) \ge \sigma_a(f^{-1})\ge \sigma_c(f^{-1})$ . But I don't know what other kind of functions satisfy the condition  I have mentioned .

Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: If the Dirichlet series of $f^{-1}$ has zeros in its half-plane of [absolute] convergence, then $\sigma_a(f) \geqslant \sigma_c(f) \geqslant \sigma_z(f^{-1}) > \sigma_c(f^{-1})$, where $$\sigma_z(g) = \sup \: \left\{ \operatorname{Re} s : \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{g(n)}{n^s} = 0\right\}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer : okay .. how do you prove this claim ?

Comment: If $H(s) = \sum \frac{f^{-1}(n)}{n^s}$ has a zero at $s_0$ and $\operatorname{Re} s_0 > \sigma_c(f^{-1})$, then $1/H$ has a pole at $s_0$. But $\sum \frac{f(n)}{n^s} = 1/H(s)$ on the half-plane where both series converge. Since a Dirichlet series cannot have a pole in its half-plane of convergence, it follows that $\sigma_c(f) \geqslant \operatorname{Re} s_0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Ah I think the product formula for Dirichlet series you are using is valid in the half plane where both the series converges with one of them absolutely convergent ... also , if $H(f,s)$ has a zero at $s_0$, then $\Re s_0 \ge \sigma_c(f)$ always (otherwise, $H(f,s)$ would diverge at $s_0$, impossible ) right ?

Comment: That's where it can be proved by computation with series alone. But since the sum function of a Dirichlet series is holomorphic, the identity theorem implies that the product formula holds where both series converge (not necessarily absolutely).

Comment: @DanielFischer : But how do you apply identity theorem ? I mean the series may not be holomorphic at the boundary , the sum is holomorphic on the half plane of absolute convergence only, right ? ...

Comment: I am only considering the open half-planes of convergence, so I look at $H(s)$ only for $\operatorname{Re} s > \sigma_c(f^{-1})$. If we consider meromorphic continuations of the sum function to a larger half-plane (if they admit such), or only an extension to the abscissa of convergence (if possible), things get more complicated. The sum function is holomorphic on the half-plane $\operatorname{Re} s > \sigma_c$ since the convergence is locally uniform there.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Okay , I understand  . So what happens if $Re s_0=\sigma_c(f^{-1})$ , where $H(f^{-1},s)$ vanishes at $s=s_0$ ?

Comment: If $H$ has an analytic continuation to a neighbourhood of $s_0$, the same reasoning applies and we get $\sigma_c(f) \geqslant \sigma_c(f^{-1})$. If not, we need a slight modification of the argument to get the same result. If we have a sequence $(s_k)$ with $\operatorname{Re} s_k > \operatorname{Re} s_0 = \sigma_c(f^{-1})$ such that $H(s_k) \to 0$, then the sequence $1/H(s_k)$ is unbounded, and that means $\sigma_c(f) \geqslant \operatorname{Re} s_0$, for otherwise we'd have $1/H(s_k) \to 1/H(s_0)$.